# Can the bulb of the gloxi split into two by cutting it?

Tags: houseplants

Would i want to know if the two bulb halves will still shoot?[image]  Both bulbs sprouted![image][image]

Comment: can you clean the bulb up so we can see it, because right now it looks like a lump of dirt?

Answer (score 3):

Well you're about to find out, presumably, because you've already cut or broken one in half by the looks of it! Old, larger tubers can be cut in sections, but each section must have a shoot or growing point on it, just the same as with dahlia tubers, or it won't do anything other than shrivel up and die. I can't tell if there are any growth points on the one in your picture, but more information on cutting the tubers here https://dengarden.com/gardening/How-to-Grow-and-Care-for-Gloxinias